# Can a keyboard ENTER be interpreted as a string::size_type?

Tags: c++, while-loop, infinite-loop

I'm trying this code to convert integers between 0-15 to hexadecimal:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    const string hexstring = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    string str;
    string::size_type n;
    string result_str;
    while (cin >> n){
        if (n < hexstring.size()){
            result_str += hexstring[n];         
        }
    }
    cout << result_str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What I want is that when the user types:

```
12 13 14 15
```

and hits ENTER, the expected output should be:

```
CDEF
```

However, even after hitting ENTER, the user is still prompted for input. I was under the impression that an ENTER is not of type `string::size_type`, and so the `while` loop condition is violated, leading to an exit of the loop. Why is the condition still true after typing ENTER?

Comment: `\n` is a whitespace character, and `>>` skips leading whitespace. You should probably read a single line using `std::getline`, and then parse it using `std::istringstream` or with something else.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat  ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While performing formatted input (as you are), "Enter" is not a character nor a termination condition. It is just a piece of whitespace (like a space or a tab), which gets skipped over by default for the purpose of data extraction.

As such, the only thing it "does" is to trigger line buffering in your terminal client and send the characters written so far to your program, where they are processed (along with the newline, which is ignored as I just said).

If you want to read a line at a time, then do that, using `std::getline`. This will read exactly one line of input. Then you can parse it with a `std::stringstream` or some other thing.

You could [make `std::cin` *not* skip whitespace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/skipws), but then the space between your numbers would end the loop too.

Answer (score 1):

If the input will not be interrupted the loop

```
while (cin >> n){
    if (n < hexstring.size()){
        result_str += hexstring[n];         
    }
}
```

is infinite.

To interrupt the loop you could enter a non-number as for example letter 'A'.

Before the loop you could output a prompt something like

```
std::cout << "Enter a sequence of non-negative numbers. Press 'q' to quit.\n"  ;
```